# Как построить n графиков по 4ём столбцам pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Задача состоит в том, чтобы используя matplotlib.pyplot построить график по датафрейму:

```
         date           drink           city            segment  volume_litr
0  1996-01-01  Безалкогольные       Коукворт      Орден Феникса     3.762379
1  1996-01-01     Алкогольные  Литтл Уингинг  Пожиратели смерти    17.377532
2  1996-01-01     Алкогольные        Абердин      Орден Феникса    41.229288
3  1996-01-01     Алкогольные       Коукворт      Орден Феникса   116.523241
4  1996-01-01     Алкогольные       Коукворт  Пожиратели смерти    12.651664
```

По оси Oy идёт volume_litr, по Ox date (с этим проблем нет), проблема в том, как мне разбить построение на n графиков (для n городов), где на каждом графике будут две кривые (для ордена Феникса и пожирателей смерти соответственно). Понимаю, что можно разбить датафрейм на части для каждого города и потом уже графики строить, но скорее всего это можно реализовать проще через matplotlib, поэтому задал вопрос.

Comment: вам в любом случае придется так или иначе разбивать датафрейм на части, например, через группировку. Либо стоить все данные на одном графике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `Seaborn`. Пример на чуть подкрученных ваших данных. С реальными должно быть лучше.

Фактически достаточно правильно настроить `sns.relplot` и он выводит всё как вы хотите. Но возможно потом ещё через `matplotlib` нужно будет поправить какие-то параметры графика.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = """
         date           drink           city            segment  volume_litr
0  1996-01-01  Безалкогольные       Коукворт      "Орден Феникса"     3.762379
1  1996-01-01     Алкогольные  "Литтл Уингинг"  "Пожиратели смерти"    17.377532
2  1996-01-01     Алкогольные        Абердин      "Орден Феникса"    41.229288
3  1996-01-01     Алкогольные       Коукворт      "Орден Феникса"   116.523241
4  1996-01-01     Алкогольные       Коукворт  "Пожиратели смерти"    12.651664
5  1996-01-02  Безалкогольные       Коукворт      "Орден Феникса"     13.762379
6  1996-01-02     Алкогольные  "Литтл Уингинг"  "Пожиратели смерти"    7.377532
7  1996-01-02     Алкогольные        Абердин      "Орден Феникса"    21.229288
8  1996-01-02     Алкогольные       Коукворт      "Орден Феникса"   216.523241
9  1996-01-02     Алкогольные       Коукворт  "Пожиратели смерти"    22.651664"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\s+')

sns.relplot(x='date', y='volume_litr', data=df, hue='segment', col='city', kind='line')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Ещё более настраиваемый вариант с тучей параметров (можно настроить число строк и колонок и многое другое) - это `FacetGrid`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue='segment', col="city")
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'volume_litr')
```